# Big Sur Finder tab changes when focus returns to Finder

Tags: finder, big-sur, tabs

I am on Big Sur 11.2.3.

Tabs change on Finder when I return to Finder from another desktop or switch focus to it from another application on the same desktop.

Here are the steps to reproduce this

1. I open Finder, I have three tabs. lets call them Tab-1, Tab-2 and
   Tab-3.
2. I select the Tab-2 and open a file from a folder on this tab.
3. The focus shifts to the application that opens the file.
4. Now, I click on the Finder icon in the dock.
5. Mac takes me back to Finder
   **but the focus has shifted to Tab-3**. I expect the focus to stay with Tab-2.

**Why is this happening?** Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Incidentally it is always the Tab on the **right hand most side** that gets the focus when I come back to Finder. So, the shit is not simply to the next tab. for example, if I start on Tab-1 then I end up on Tab-3 (not Tab-2). It always shifts to right hand most tab.